# How to search for a Char in a given location in a list of Strings, and then separate them into sublists?

Tags: string, list, haskell, filter

I'm sorry if it sounds really confusing, but I just can't explain it any better than that. I'm trying to take a Char from a user and filter words from a word bank that have the given Char in a specific place. For example, if the Char given was 'e':

```
---- matches ["ally","cool","good"]
-e-- matches ["beta","deal"]
e--e matches ["else"]
--e- matches ["flew","ibex"]
---e matches ["hope"]
```

I'll need to then take the largest list and return it as the new word bank, then repeat until there is only one word left. It's a difficult thing for me to wrap my head around. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

While many people's first choice would be regular expressions, this task can be done pretty easily without them.  First, you need to decide on a data type.  I would make one that represents my pattern in an easier to use form than just a string:

```
data Character = Wildcard | Literal Char deriving (Eq, Show)
type Pattern = [Character]

buildPattern :: String -> Pattern
buildPattern [] = []
buildPattern ('-':rest) = Wildcard : buildPattern rest
buildPattern (x:rest) = Literal x : buildPattern rest

-- buildPattern "-e---" = [Wildcard, Literal 'e', Wildcard, Wildcard, Wildcard]
```

Now we need to build a way to match a string against a pattern, this is the real meat of the problem, and I will intentionally leave some holes for you to fill in

```
match :: Pattern -> String -> Bool
match [] "" = True   -- An empty pattern matches an empty string
match [] _  = False  -- An empty pattern doesn't match a non-empty string
match (Wildcard:pat) (_:rest) = ???
match (Literal c:pat) (x:rest)
    | c == x    = ???
    | otherwise = False
```

I'll leave it up to you to figure out what to put in those holes.  Remember that the `Wildcard` should match any character, and a `Literal` should match only that exact character.  You'll have to use recursion here, but it isn't too difficult.  If you get stuck, comment and tell me how far you got.

---

Now, you could also solve this without making a new data type at all and just using built-in Haskell functions.  Something like

```
type Pattern = String

match :: Pattern -> String -> Bool
match pat str = and [c == x | (c, x) <- zip pat str, c /= '-']
```

(This isn't quite right on purpose, it doesn't check for the lengths to be the same.)

However, I would recommend against this.  Why?  What if you suddenly got the requirement that your patterns need to also handle the form `--[ea]-` to match both `then` and `than`?  With the data type representation, you can easily extend it to be

```
import Data.List (span)

data Character = Wildcard | Literal Char | Class [Char] deriving (Eq, Show)
type Pattern = [Character]

buildPattern :: String -> Pattern
buildPattern [] = []
buildPattern ('-':pat) = Wildcard : buildPattern pat
buildPattern ('[':pat) = Class chars : buildPattern (drop 1 rest)
    where (chars, rest) = span (/= ']')
    -- span (/= ']') "ea]-" == ("ea", "]-")
    -- essentially splits at a condition, but we want to drop the ']'
    -- off of it so I used (drop 1 rest)

match :: Pattern -> String -> Bool
match [] "" = True
match [] _  = False
match (Wildcard :pat) (_:rest) = ...
match (Literal c:pat) (x:rest) = ...
match (Class  cs:pat) (x:rest) = ...
```

And you can just continue build up your pattern language very easily to support many different kinds of patterns.

---

If you want to use a `Map` to store your word bank, you could do something like

```
-- This is recommended because many functions in Data.Map conflict with built-ins
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

-- code from above goes here

wordBank :: M.Map Int [String]
wordBank = M.fromList
    [ (1, ["a"])
    , (2, ["as", "at", "or", "on", "in", "is"])
    , (3, ["and", "the", "and", "are", "dog", "cat"])
    , (4, ["then", "than", "that", "bath", "from", "moon")
    -- ...
    ]

wordsOfLength :: Int -> [String]
wordsOfLength len = fromMaybe [] $ M.lookup len wordBank
-- Default to an empty list if the lookup fails (i.e. len = -1)

wordsMatching :: Pattern -> [String]
wordsMatching pat =
    let possibles = wordsOfLength $ length pat
    in filter (match pat) possibles
-- Or just
-- wordMatching pat = filter (match pat) $ wordsOfLength $ length pat
```

Comment: Could you provide an example input?  Are you wanting to be able to enter something like `"these are some words"` and get out `["these", "are", "some", "words"]`, then use the matching function to filter it?

Comment: It would be similar to a hangman game. The user would enter a guess in the form of a character and the character would be placed in each slot in a word composed of blanks of a given length (if the user wanted a word that was 5 characters long it would be -----). It would divide the words from the word bank  up into sublists by where the character was in the words and then return the largest one in an attempt to make the game difficult to win. The character would be placed in the slot that yielded the most word possibilities. Sorry, kind of hard to explain.

Comment: @raine Well, you could use what I've shown so far to build part of that, but the fun of programming is figuring out how to fit all the bits together.  Supposing you wanted a hard-coded word list, I would store it all in a `Data.Map.Map` structure.  You could have the key be the length, and the values be a list of all the words of that length, so `lookup 4 wordBank` might return `["help", "else", "want", "then"]`, and `lookup 3 wordBank` might return `["the", "are", "and", "cat"]`.  Then you can use `filter (match pattern)` on the resulting list to get all the ones that match that pattern.

Comment: Thanks, you've been a great help!

Comment: I took your advice but I'm still confused. How could I use your suggestions in (preferably) one function that takes a dictionary and returns a list of Strings (words)?

Comment: Thank you for the edits. I really like the word matching function, but I already filter the words by length in my main. Any suggestions on how I can use wordMatching without a function? replacing wordsOfLength with Dictionary only creates issues as Dictionary is of type [[Char]] not [String].

Comment: @raine I'm not sure I understand your question.  In what way do you envision using `wordsMatching` without a function?  Which function?  And what is Dictionary?  Also, `[[Char]]` is the same as `[String]`, since `String = [Char]`.

Comment: I may just be confused about: let possibles = wordsOfLength $ length pat -- could you explain what that line does again?

Comment: It just assigns the result of `wordsOfLength $ length pat` to the name `possibles` so that I can use it later in `filter (match pat) possibles`.  The comment underneath shows an alternative definition that doesn't use the intermediate variable.  They're equivalent though, the compiler will produce identical code from both.

Comment: I keep getting the error that it expects a [String] and can't be compared to my dictionary which is a [[Char]]. I guess it considers them different? Any way I can fix that? Here is what I wrote it as: wordsOfLength length = fromMaybe [] $ M.lookup length mediumDict <- mediumDict is the dictionary I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is by using the `Data.List.Split` library. There is a very cool function called `splitOn`. So if you have a pattern string

```
[ghci] let pat = "e--e"
[ghci] import Data.List.Split
[ghci] splitOn "e" pat
Loading package split-0.2.2 ... linking ... done.
["","--",""]
[ghci]
```

Notice that you only need the lengths of the values within the arrays. Hence, if you create a function that gets the length of each of the items within ...

```
[ghci] let f c str = map length $ splitOn [c] str
```

Then, this function can be used for:

```
[ghci] f 'e' pat
[0,2,0]
[ghci] f 'e' "else"
[0,2,0]
[ghci] f 'e' "beta"
[1,2]
```

Now lists can directly be compared as below ...

```
[ghci] [0,2,0] == [0,2,0]
True
[ghci] [0,2,0] == [0,2,1]
False
[ghci]
```

So your match function should take a pattern and character and another string and return of the lengths of the splits match or not.

```
[ghci] let g c pat str = (f c pat) == (f c str)
[ghci] g 'e' pat "else"
True
[ghci] g 'e' pat "whatever"
False
```

So finally, you can partically apply this function and map to a list of strings ...

```
[ghci] map (g 'e' pat) $ words "cafeen else I die!!"
[False,True,False,False]
```

Or match any other pattern ...

```
[ghci] map (g 'e' "-e--") $ words "This beta version wont deal with everything"
[False,True,False,False,True,False,False]
```

And also ...

```
[ghci] map (g 'e' "----") $ words "This beta version wont deal with everything"
[True,False,False,True,False,True,False]
```

EDIT:

Dictionaries in Haskell are part of the `Data.Map` module. Dictionaries comprise of name-value pairs. Now functions in Haskell are first-class values. Hence, the named arguments in the dictionaries can be functions. So you set up a list of named conditions, with functions as their values ...

You can create a dictionary of conditions like so:

```
[ghci] import Data.Map
[ghci] let someDict = fromList [("C1",  Data.List.map (g 'e' "----") . words), 
                                ("C2",  Data.List.map (g 'e' "-e--") . words)]
```

Then you can `lookup` a function and just call it. (Note that since this function will be within a `Maybe`, youll need to apply it like a `Functor` ...

```
[ghci] import Control.Applicative
[ghci] Data.Map.lookup "C2" someDict <*> Just "This beta version wont deal with everything"
Just [False,True,False,False,True,False,False]
```

Hope this helps ...

Comment: Awesome! Any tips on how I could use this with a  large dictionary, preferably within a single function?